# 'MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.' error on self-hosted Bitbucket Windows runner

Tags: .net, windows, msbuild, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to create a Bitbucket pipeline running on self-hosted Windows Runner for a .NET Framework project. So this is how my bitbucket-pipeline.yml file looks like:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        runs-on:
          - "windows"
        script:
          - nuget.exe restore .\MyProject.sln -source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json;http://nuget.mycompany.com/nuget"
          - msbuild .\MyProject.sln
```

But I get this error on pipeline:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: .\MyProject.sln
```

When I add `ls` script before build, I can view that the solution file is just there. I also tried the absolute path of the file.

At the beginning of the pipeline, when cloning the repo, it resolves this Unhandled error that might be related to this issue:

```
Cloning into 'C:\Windows\system32\a\bin\..\t\3adbb782-beda-5972-b527-6102602fdbb8\1684652729856\build'...

Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at GitCredentialManager.GitProcess.get_Version()
   at GitCredentialManager.GitProcessConfiguration.GetCanonicalizeTypeArg(GitConfigurationType type)
   at GitCredentialManager.GitProcessConfiguration.TryGet(GitConfigurationLevel level, GitConfigurationType type, String name, String& value)
   at GitCredentialManager.GitConfigurationExtensions.TryGet(IGitConfiguration config, String name, Boolean isPath, String& value)
   at GitCredentialManager.Settings.<GetSettingValues>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at GitCredentialManager.Settings.TryGetSetting(String envarName, String section, String property, String& value)
   at GitCredentialManager.Settings.GetTrace2Settings()
   at GitCredentialManager.CommandContext..ctor(String[] argv)
```

I thought the error was about the max char limit on windows but it seems lesser than the limit. How can I handle this error ?

Comment: My first reaction was to report this to the vendor, then finding out  [this exact error has been reported in a comment in December 2001](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-Pipeline-Window-Runner/Windows-Runners-EAP-Getting-Started/ba-p/1875195#M8). It might be worth to first of all double check if there is already an issue about it in the Atlassian Bitbucket Windows Pipelines Runnner issue tracker. Have you checked any vendor resources so far for the issue?

Comment: Yes I checked Atlassian support and didn't find any notable issue. I will ask their community too

Comment: The link in my comment is from community, from below the EAP announcement of the windows runner. Ca. half a year later, [stable release was announced (May 2022)](https://bitbucket.org/blog/windows-runners), but I could neither find a Bitbucket repository for (at least the installer of) it nor the Jira tracker. For self service perhaps double-check all the prerequisites match? https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-runners-for-windows/

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `C:\Windows\system32` directory? It may be a permissions issue. The Windows OS restricts access to and changes within the `Windows` directory. (The Atlassian documentation show an example of `C:\Users\your_user_name\atlassian_runners`.)